# Change button content foreground or stroke color using a custom button style

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I try to change the Stroke of an Ellipse that is the Content of a Button on mouse hover using a custom button style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Why does only the TextBlock with the Text "Working" change its Foreground property?

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}">
    <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="{x:Bind MyButton.Foreground, Mode=OneWay}"></Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind MyButton.Foreground, Mode=OneWay}" Text="Not Working" />
                <TextBlock Text="Working" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your visual state animation is modifying the `ContentPresenter`'s foreground not the `Button` (`MyButton`)'s foreground.
2. Use a `ContentControl` instead of a `ContentPresenter` in order to access other properties within the template.
3. Access some other control's `Foreground` such as the following.

Code:

```
<StackPanel>
     <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="{x:Bind MyText.Foreground, Mode=OneWay}"></Ellipse>
     <TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind MyText.Foreground, Mode=OneWay}" Text="Not Working" />
     <TextBlock x:Name="MyText" Text="Working" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Switching from ContentPresenter to ContentControl works like a charm. Thanks!